# Create model from another model - with Many2one fields - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

consider these two models:

```py
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order'
    _inherit = ['product.product']

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Production Date")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.production.order.lines', 'production_order', states={'finished': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, string="Order lines", copy=True)
    print_orders = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order', 'production_orders', string="Print Orders")

class bsi_print_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread','mrp.worksheet.contract'] 

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Print Date")
    production_orders = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order")
    due_date = fields.Date(string="Due Date")
    state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('awaitingraw','Awaiting raw materials'),
        ('wip','Work in Progress'),
        ('delivered','Delivered'),
        ('cancel','Cancel'),
    ], string="State")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
```

I want to create a new record from `bsi.production.order` to `bsi.print.order`, having specifically two fields for it, `state` and `production_order`, the latter being the `name` field of `bsi.production.order`.

You can see this field on `bsi.print.order` is a `Many2one` field, while in `bsi.production.order` is a `Char`, this is what I've tried so far:

```py
@api.multi
def create_print(self): 
    self.env['bsi.print.order'].create({
        'production_orders': 'name',
        'state': 'draft',
    })
```

If I leave the `state` into the dict, it creates correctly, but if I try like this, it throws me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 948, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\mrp_worksheet_contract\models\models.py", line 262, in create_print
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\mrp_worksheet_contract\models\models.py", line 466, in create
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\mrp_worksheet_contract\models\models.py", line 20, in create
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 508, in new_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\mail\mail_thread.py", line 381, in create
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 372, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4101, in create
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 508, in new_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 4245, in _create
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 171, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\sql_db.py", line 247, in execute
DataError: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para integer: «name»
LINE 1: ...ES(nextval('bsi_print_order_id_seq'), 'PO-00009', 'name', fa...
```

So, since this is a `Many2one` in `bsi.print.order`, What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Seems like instead of passing the bsi.production.order `name` field into `production_orders` Many2one field, it is actually trying to create the bsi.print.order with it's own `name` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Odoo, Many2one field store integer value / ID of target table.

In your case, you are trying to pass *char* value that's lead to error.

Try with following code:

```py
@api.multi
def create_print(self):
    # You need to pass ID as per your requirement
    rec_production_order = self.env['bsi.production.order'].browse(1)
    self.env['bsi.print.order'].create({
        'production_orders': rec_production_order.id,
        'name': rec_production_order.name
        'state': 'draft',
    })
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much, but now my model is messed up, Integrity error and cannot even create production orders, I think it has to do with ´rec_production_order = self.env['bsi.production.order].browse(1)´ line, not sure, gonna modify it and try as soon as I wake up, Thank You again

Comment: This solves my question, so Thank you very much, I'll open a new one for any other issue :)